# Is "aliae alias in partes" an idiom of some kind?

Tags: idiom

In Fabulae Faciles, section 82, I do not understand the expression "aliae alias in partes". Is this some kind of idiom? The phrase is:

> Postquam tamen pauca mīlia passuum ā lītore Trōiae prōgressī sunt,
> tanta tempestās subitō coörta est ut nūlla nāvium cursum tenēre
> posset, **sed aliae alias in partes disicerentur.**

"... but they were scattered into other parts of another." Seems to make no sense. However, I am interpreting aliae as a genitive, is that wrong?

Comment: Does my answer satisfy your question, or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 6):

First, *aliae* is nominative plural here, not genitive singular, and refers back to the *navium* of the previous clause.

Second, when you have two different forms of *alius* together, you get what's called distribution.  It's essentially "one to one, another to another" (in singular) or "some to some, others to others" (in plural), depending on the case. In this example, it would read more like:

> "..., but so that some ships were scattered into some parts and other ships into other parts."

The "scattered-ness" is being distributed throughout the group so as to emphasize the lack of uniformity in action.

Allen and Greenough §316 (who call it "a double statement") give a few examples:

> alius aliud petit, one man seeks one thing, another seeks another thing.
> iussit alios alibi fodere (Liv. 44.33), he ordered different persons to dig in different places.
> alii alios loco resistebant (B.C. 2.39), some halted in one place, some in another place.